# how to access 'as "array"' in controllers

Tags: angularjs

```
<md-input ng-model="company_id"></md-input>

<md-input ng-model="user_id"></md-input>

<md-list-item class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="item in all_users | filter :{ 'company_id' : company_id } | filter:{'user_id' : id_State } as filteredarray">
    <md-checkbox ng-model="selected[item.user_id]"></md-checkbox>
    <h3 class="md-body-2" style="color: white;">{{item.user_firstname}}</h3>
    <md-list-item>
```

---

```
app.controller('connectionCtrl', function ($scope) {

   console.log($scope.filteredarray)

})
```

ng-repeat="item in items | filter: filterexp as filteredarray"

filteredarray is not accessible in controller....

$scope.filteredarray is always null when i'm log the value in console.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a code sample or clarify your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more different but elegant approach to do it is to create a custom filter function where you need to pass the object from iteration and push it in new array based on your actual filter.

So it would be like this

```
<md-list-item class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="item in all_users | filter:customFilterFn">
```

Having inputs like

```
<md-input ng-model="company_id"></md-input>
<md-input ng-model="user_id"></md-input>
```

Now define the function in controller

```
$scope.filteredItems = [];
$scope.customFilterFn = function(item)
{ 
    if(item.companyid === this.company_id && item.userid === this.user_id)
    {
        $scope.filteredItems.push(item);
        return true; // this will be listed in the results
    }    
    return false; // otherwise it won't be within the results
};
```

Now filteredItems would contain the filtered data.

Comment: i have two or more filters, in the dom pls check ... how can we check with if condition for more filters

Comment: what is user_company_id,user_hod_id ?means where they are defined?Please edit the questions to clear the things

Comment: still it is not clear.you have shown it defined in ng-model as input so user gives input to these fields right?so why cant you get the data `$scope.company_id` and check it in if condition